# sparklyr::spark_write_jdbc Does not Accept Spark Dataframe?

Tags: r, sql-server, apache-spark-sql, databricks, sparklyr

I am working within Databricks, trying to use the sparklyr function spark_write_jdbc to write a dataframe to a SQL Server table. The server name/driver etc are correct and work, as I successfully used sparklyr::spark_read_jdbc() earlier in the code.

Per the documentation ([here](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/sparklyr/versions/1.3.1/topics/spark_write_jdbc)), spark_write_jdbc should accept a Spark Dataframe.

I used SparkR::createDataFrame() to convert the dataframe I was working with to a Spark dataframe.

Here is the relevant code:

```
events_long_test <- SparkR::createDataFrame(events_long, schema = NULL, samplingRatio = 1, numPartitions = NULL)


sparklyr::spark_write_jdbc(events_long_test, 
                name ="who_status_long_test" , 
                options = list(url = url, 
                               user = user,
                               driver = "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver",
                               password = pw,
                               dbtable = "who_status_long_test"))
```

However, when I run this, it gives me the following error:

> Error in UseMethod("spark_write_jdbc") : Error in UseMethod("spark_write_jdbc") :
> no applicable method for 'spark_write_jdbc' applied to an object of class "SparkDataFrame"

I have searched around and cannot find other people asking about this error. Why would it say this function cannot work with a Spark Dataframe, when the documentation says it does?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

What is in events_long? the syntax is correct and make sure your connection properties in options are correct. Make sure that events_long_test  is a spark dataframe not a table.

Comment: This doesn't provide an answer, it's more guidance for further investigation/testing regarding the issue. It would fit better as a comment to the question.